# When making a $.post request with jQuery, my data is coming back undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I am attempting to make a simple **post** request, but for some reason the data I'm sending is being returned as undefined. I've checked the console to make sure the data exists before making the post request and it is there. If you look below, the `var $description` takes its value from a simple html input field. The data is text and does exist as I said. Why is the alert returning `'undefined'`?

```
$('#addTodo').click(function (event) {

            $('#success').hide();
            $('#failure').hide();

            $description = $('#todoDescription').val();

            $.post('/todos', {description: $description})
                .done(function(data) {

                    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data.description);

            });

        });
```

This is how the request is handled on the server:

```
app.post('/todos', function (req, res) {
    var body = req.body;

    console.log('description: ' + body.description);
    res.json(body);

});
```

Comment: `The data is text` if the data is text it wont have a property called `description`

Comment: Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` what are you getting in console?

Comment: When I console.log(data) it returns [object Object], so how do I access the object's property called description?

Comment: When I console.log(JSON.stringify(data)), the console shows {}, and empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is undefined, check what do you return from server. You can see it in firebug or any other browser developer tool. Also, call console.log(data) and see your data directly in console.

And please, doublecheck, that "description" exist from server, it can be typo. Like "desrciption" or something like that

Comment: I edited my post to show the code from the server. When I console.log(data) , the console shows [object Object], and when I console.log(JSON.stringify(data)), the console shows {}, and empty object.

Comment: Ok, that mean that your server return empty object. Investigate server side. For clarify - you send data to SERVER, but you also need RESEND it from server, if you wants to use it again for done callback. Also, you can simply use $description instead of data.description and it will be work like a charm,

Comment: I edited my question to show the code that I'm using on the server. You can take a quick look above.

Comment: Is it nodejs? Looks like req.body is empty.

Comment: Yes it's node.js, I have an npm installed called body-parser. The app should be using it as such: app.use(bodyParser.json()); So should I just res.json(req)?

Comment: Try to res.json({"description": "test"});
Also, try to set json header : res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); And as a final : res.send(JSON.stringify({ description:1 }, null, 3));
try it step by step.

Comment: res.json({"description": "test"});  Worked as expected. Sorry to say, I don't know how or where to set json header like you said. I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: if res.json({"description": "test"}); works as expexted, that mean that you maybe need to return req and check what is will be returned. Do not set any headers, it should works as is

Comment: In anyway, i'm not a nodejs guru :) If my answers was help, check my answer as a solution and up it please. Thank you. Maybe you need to create another one question to nodejs specialists. Have a good day )

Answer (score 0):

as a starting, instead of doing

```
alert( "Data Loaded: " + data.description);
```

you should try

```
alert( "Data Loaded: " + data);
```

here you are printing the output from the server, before you access anything inside the data.

and dont forget to, convert it to JSON, before accessing properties inside data

also make sure(just before sending it from the server), that you are sending proper data from the server

Comment: When I alert the data, after converting it to JSON, it's an empty object. I don't understand this. In the $.post request, I am sending this object: {description: $description}, which contains data. The var $description contains text from an input field in the html, so where does all the data disappear to?

Comment: the data coming back in .done function is not the data you provided(if you are expecting {description: $description}). it is the reply data from server, which is why i said you should verify your server too